# Need to abstract collections of objects (C#)

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism

In the following simplified example, I need to abstract Collection classes in such a way that `PrintFruitsAndEaters(oranges, orangeEaters);` or `PrintFruitsAndEaters(apples, appleEaters);` 
becomes possible:

```
abstract class Fruit
abstract class FruitEater

class Apple : Fruit
class AppleEater : FruitEater
class Orange : Fruit
class OrangeEater : FruitEater

class AppleCollection : List<Apple>
class OrangeCollection : List<Orange>
class AppleEaterCollection : List<AppleEater>
class OrangeEaterCollection : List<OrangeEater>
```

I've tried templatizing the method and collection classes, but i need to access methods specific to Fruit and FruitEater classes:

```
class FruitCollection<T> : List<T>
class FruitEaterCollection<T> : List<T>

void PrintFruitsAndEaters<T, S>(FruitCollection<T> fruits, FruitEaterCollection<S> eaters)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then you want this:

```
void PrintFruitsAndEaters<T, S>(
    FruitCollection<T> fruits,
    FruitEaterCollection<S> eaters)
        where T : Fruit
        where S : FruitEater
{
    // ...
}
```

This will constrain the `T` and `S` types as you require; calling the method with a `FruitCollection<T>`, where the `T` cannot be guaranteed to be `Fruit` or a subtype, will result in a compile-time error.  Same with `S` and `FruitEater`.

Because of the constraint, when working with a value of type `T` you will be able to access members of the `Fruit` class, and when working with a value of type `S` you will be able to access members of the `FruitEater` class.

Note that, as per Brian's (deleted) answer, you might want to add constraints to the collection types too:

```
class FruitCollection<T> : List<T> where T : Fruit { }
class FruitEaterCollection<T> : List<T> where T : FruitEater { }
```

But **this will still not allow you to omit the constraints on the method.**

(Also, inheriting `List<T>` is an evil thing to do, instead use `IList<T>`)

Comment: @Brian: Wrong.  Applying the constraints to the collections, but not the method, will cause the method to fail to compile at all, since `T` and `S` will not be compatible with the generic arguments to the types.  The compiler will not infer these constraints for you.  Applying the constraints to the collection types too may be nice for the API, but does not ultimately solve the problem.

Comment: @cdhowie: you are right.  We need covariance.  I am dumping my answer, because I am on a Mac right now and I don't want to reboot :)  Deleting my comments too.

Comment: @Brian: Well, you'd still have to supply generic arguments with covariance.  :)  Your answer would be really slick, if it worked.  :(  I've incorporated the suggestion to add constraints to the collection types into my answer, but have pointed out that doing that alone will not solve the problem.  Hope you don't consider that plagarism.  :)  I had the same thought as you did initially, but when I started to mock up an implementation I found that it falls apart pretty quickly.

Comment: @cdhowie: Yeah, I apologize.  My answer was not complete and I was sure I was compiling correctly in my brain!  :)  As much as I love/use generics, they can get beastly.  Take my up-vote as an apology.  I am addicted to this friggin site.  Need to rest.  :)

Comment: +1. Glad you clarified that it's best to put constraints on the collections too. `class FruitCollection<T> : List<T>` is a pretty senseless declaration; it doesn't prevent a `FruitCollection<Vegetable>`. I would go a step further and change `FruitEater` to `FruitEater<T> where T : Fruit`.

Comment: @Brian: No apology needed. I've posted plenty of stuff here only to realize it doesn't work. Brains aren't perfect!

Comment: @Ani: +1 Perhaps, yeah.  I don't want to completely rewrite his API for him though, but hopefully he will read your comment.

Comment: @cdhowie: thanks for the answer, that will do! and why inheriting from List<T> is an evil thing?

Comment: @kateroh: Because this makes the `List<T>` type part of your type definition.  If you later wanted to use the functionality of `LinkedList<T>` for performance reasons, you would change the binary compatibility of your assembly, causing anything compiled against an old version to fail to link.  You should instead implement the `IList<T>` interface and delegate the interface methods to the corresponding methods of the actual list implementation you are using.  This will allow you to change what list class you use willy-nilly without breaking compatibility.

Comment: @cdhowie: thanks for explanation, makes sense. im actually using IEnumerable<T> for the same reason you described. List<T> was given for simplicity purposes. thanks!

Comment: @kateroh: Ah, cool. Then you're not doing anything evil at all. :)